# What is the difference between 問い and 質問?

Tags: word-choice, wago-and-kango

I found this explanation but I don't really understand it.

> 【１】「**問い**」は、単に尋ね聞くこと。
>
> 【２】「**質問**」は、広く一般的に疑問点を問う場合に用いる。教室や会議など公の場での問いに用いることが多いが、私的、個人的な場でも用いる。([source](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/11087/meaning/m0u/%E5%95%8F%E3%81%84/))

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/53829/when-would-you-use-相互-as-opposed-to-お互い/53832#53832

Comment: ^ でも、「お互い vs 相互」とは逆で、「問い vs 質問」は和語のほうが漢語より硬いですよね。。。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My opinion is different from what the dictionary says...

As a noun, 問い is perhaps closer to *problem*, but is a fairly literary and "big" word. Basically it's only used in the following cases:

1. In serious examinations, where [～せよ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/49010/5010) is still used.

   > 以下の**問い**に日本語で答えよ。
2. Important and fundamental questions/problems that may not have an answer (philosophical question, political question, ...).

   > - そのニュースは、平和とは何なのかという**問い**を国民に投げかけた。
   > - 「時間とは何か」という**問い**に物理学者は挑んでいる。
3. As a stiff synonym for (good) 疑問 in a context related to education.

   > 英語学習における初心者の**問い**に答える記事
4. In old novels, stiff literary works, etc.

   > よく五音をいい分け、人と問答会話するをもって、なんぴとにてもこの怪声に対し**問い**を発せば、いちいちその答えを得という ([source](https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/001021/files/49268_42258.html))

質問 is a common word, and it refers to a question thrown to somebody else, expecting a concrete answer, either casually or formally. "Where is the station?" is a typical 質問 but usually not called a 問い. If you ask something to yourself ("What should I do next?"), that's never a 質問, either.

Maybe we can add this to ["wago is more stiff than kango equivalent" list](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/58363/5010).

Answer (score 2):

問い{とい}, which is sometimes shortened to 問{とい} is mostly used only in examinations, as in 問い1 (Question 1). 質問{しつもん} is the general term you call a sentence that asks for information, as in 先生、質問があります。(Teacher, I have a question.) You can call a question on an examination as a 質問, but you cannot refer to a question you ask someone as a 問い.

While we're at it, there are at least two other Japanese words that are also translated into English as "question" and that is 問題{もんだい} and 疑問{ぎもん}. 問題 is just the same as 問い when referring to questions (or problems) on an examination. 疑問 means doubt, or a matter that needs to be dealt with or considered as in その必要性{ひつようせい}について疑問が生{しょう}じる (A question arises as to whether it is necessary.)